# Persisting margin/padding at bottom of ul li list inside div container

Tags: css, html-lists, margin

```css
ul,
ol,
li {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top:0 }
  ul ul,
  ul ol,
  ol ul,
  ol ol,
  ul li,
  li ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top:0 }
    
.columns{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 20px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div data-type="vertical" class="responsive-tabs responsive-tabs-boxed">
                 <ul data-group="tabs-group-default" class="resp-tabs-list text-center tabs-group-default">
                   <li>Services</li>
                   <li>Industries</li>
                   <li>Advice &amp; Testing</li>
                   <li>Treatments</li>
                 </ul>
              <div data-group="tabs-group-default" class="resp-tabs-container text-left tabs-group-default">
                  <div>
                   <ul>
                    <li>Supply of cold-/hotforged and CNC-machined metal (round) products:</li>
                     <ul><li>To standard specifications UNS/ASTM - DIN - BS - AFNOR - GOST</li>
                      <li>Specials according to technical drawing<br></li>
                     </ul>
                    <li>Heat- &amp; surface treatments and material coatings, on all metals</li>
                    <li>Advice on material and coating applications</li>
                    <li>Inhouse testing equipment like saltspray, UV testing, ultra thin layer thickness measuring etc.</li>
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                  <ul class="columns" data-columns="2">
                    <li>Valves</li>
                    <li>Chemical industries</li>
                    <li>Maritime</li>
                    <li>Water treatment</li>
                    <li>Energy</li>
                    <li>Offshore &amp; Shipbuilding</li>
                    <li>Oil &amp; Gas</li>
                    <li>Food industries</li>
                    <li>Aviation</li>
                    <li>Rails &amp; Construction</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
```

I have a bootstrap boxed accordion which shows 4 listed divs. 
2 of these divs shown to the right of this accordion also have lists.
The first seems to get extra white space at the bottom so my next section isn't properly outlined. I don't know what it is, padding, margin or?...I set in the css for ul, li, ul ul etc all padding & margin on 0. Removing inner bullets didn't work as well.

Still it exists, whereas the other div with ul and li aligns as expected. 
Adding more lines of text doesn't influence this space, it seems to be around 16-20 px. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VjRo.jpg)

I am new here, not sure the added picture will be visible, sorry.
Anyone any idea?

Comment: This is hard to diagnose without the code and easy to diagnose with. Have you tried opening it in chrome/firefox and checking out the developer tab? Copy your code to jsfiddle and I can take a look. And also, Welcome!

Comment: Maybe you should look at ul, it has a default padding-left: 40px.

Comment: Thanks Arlyon, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/Banter23/qxkr6zg4/  hope it is clear enough. Especially because the 2nd part (the columns class) works fine and aligns the same as the other divs in the accordiion, it is for me unclear why it happens. I will try to upload my whole site to hidden map if that is better? I mean to my ftp server, it is my own company I am making a new website.

Comment: #Evgeny  I did, that is why in css I changed it to 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D I did, thanks for the tip, I added it.

Comment: I solved it by referring the 1st div also to its own new class with just 1 column-count in the css... strange but it works, not by clicking on the different accordion tabs the text is nicely outlined and the pictures below don't move....

Answer (score 0):

You can set font-size of ordered list(ol) and unordered list(ul) as 0px it will remove that space.